# Width and height properties for a website loaded in a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, embedding

I was previously trying to do this in an iframe. Now I have this working in a DIV, but am stuck with attaining the properties I require.

When trying to change the properieies of the 'siteloader' it ignores the embedded website for some reason, so I can't change the embedded website to 100% width and height. I can however do this for background of the 'siteloader' div.

I've attached all my code and a screenshot for you

CSS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">    </script>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    background: #000;
    margin: 0;

}

#siteloader {
    background: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    marginwidth:0;
    hspace:0;
    vspace:0;
    z-index: ;

}


</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="siteloader">
        <script>
        var page, randomcontent=new Array()

        randomcontent[0]="http://sandberg.nl/manifesto"
        randomcontent[1]="http://wikipedia.org"
        randomcontent[2]="http://iamsterdam.com"
        randomcontent[3]="http://therevolvinginternet.com/"

        page = randomcontent[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomcontent.length)]

        $("#siteloader").html('<object data=' + page + ' >');
        </script>

    </div>    
</body>
```

Screengrab

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting `body,html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` ?

Comment: have you had chance to review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my original comment try this:

```
html,body{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your CSS:

```
#siteloader object {
width:100%;
}
```

works on this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/z54fZ/